# What is the big block of javascript that i see at the beginning of some html pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to increase my literacy of source code, however often times when I view page source for a site i will find a huge wall of what appears to be javascript code.

A good example would be this site:
http://www.torontossc.com/

When I view the page source, I have no idea how to deal with that huge wall, so I have a few questions/logical deductions.

1. The code wall is in `<script>` tags, so I'm assuming it must be javascript. But I'm confused about why it's presented in such an unreadable/cluttered format. Surely there must be a reason for that.
2. I downloaded the source code and looked at the html page, and noticed that when I'm not viewing the source at run time, that block isn't there- There's only an externally referenced script in its place. So is the wall of code I'm seeing the actual script itself, that runs on page load?
3. I did further digging and found out that the script is part of the facebook sdk. So does this mean that any time i see a wall of code like this, it's usually a script imported for use as part of an API/for integration with another website? If that's the case, then should i assume that the clutter and density of it is just for compactness
4. If my above assumptions are correct, then would learning javascript allow me to fully understand that code wall?

I hope I've answered my own question through deduction, but hopefully someone can confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: The big wall of javascript is [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

Comment: No. That code is minified and is not intended to be human-readable, but to make loading faster by saving file size on whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code wall is in tags, so I'm assuming it must be javascript.

Yes, it's clearly printed right there: `<script type="text/javascript">`.

> But I'm confused about why it's presented in such an unreadable/cluttered format. Surely there must be a reason for that.

It's [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), a form of obfuscation which makes JavaScript smaller to download and more difficult to reverse engineer.

> I downloaded the source code and looked at the html page...

That probably broke a lot of things. You can't just download a page without downloading all of it's relatively-referenced paths.

> So does this mean that any time i see a wall of code like this, ...

No, there's nothing you can tell about the code except that it's

1. inline
2. minified

> If my above assumptions are correct, then would learning javascript allow me to fully understand that code wall?

No, nobody *writes* code that way, and nobody (easily) understands code written that way. A computer compressed/minified the code, and to understand it you need to learn JavaScript, and then unminify the code, which is a far from perfect process. Many forms of minification are "destructive" in that it's impossible to arrive back at the original source code. Human-readable tokens are often turned into single characters, and there is no way to undo this process, the original human-readable names are lost.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple.